# What is the name of this tool that is used to clamp a piece of wood for drilling?

Tags: tools, drill, furniture

What is the name of this tool in the picture?

[image: the tool is used to clamp a piece of wood to a furniture]

It seems that the tool is used to clamp a piece of wood to a furniture to avoid cracking it when drilling holes? What precisely does it do?

[image: avoid cracking it when drilling holes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a G-Clamp (or C-Clamp, or F-Clamp, or whatever other kind of clamp works) with a piece of scrap wood.
The clamp clamps the scrap wood to the back of your workpiece so that, when the drill bit pops through, it doesn't break the back of the workpiece but instead drills a neat exit hole.

Comment: Some clamps include rubber pads so they won't scratch the wood.  If your clamp doesn't have pads like this, you may want to insert some padding (such as a rag folded a few times) between the clamp and the wood.

Comment: The ones in the picture look more like F-style clamps than C-clamps, though the premise is the same. Average homeowners are more likely to own a C-clamp than an F-style clamp, too.

Comment: I have always called them bar clamps , most of mine are on pipe, but I have these smaller ones also.

Comment: Thanks all. You just saved me in the middle of the installation! This is the first time ever I've encountered something from IKEA that is not self-contained with the necessary tools ;-)